# Delete rows based off blank cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I am trying to delete blank rows in a range

My code looks like this :

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, counter As Long

i = 1

Range("B1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5).Select

Set rng = Range("G2", ActiveCell)

Range("G2").Select

For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    If rng.Cells(i) = "" Then
       rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next
```

So, hmqcnoesy has kindly helped me solve the error message. The variables should be Dimmed as LONG not INTEGER because integer can not hold as big a number for all my rows of data

Also, Jon49 gave me some code that was much mroe efficient for this process:

```
Dim r1 As Range  'Using Tim's range.     
Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("G2"),Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5))   
    'Delete blank cell rows. 
r1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Set r1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should try using type `Long` for `i` and `counter`.  Using `Integer` causes an overflow, at least in newer versions of Excel, where there are over 1 million rows in a worksheet.

Comment: Yes, counter also should be Long.  I've updated that, thanks.

Comment: Hey so i tried long and the code does go thru and delete rows (Thanks =) ) now the problem is. it just doesnt stop. and continues deleting down the column . Would u have any suggestions?

Comment: You might try starting the loop at the Rows.Count number and loop "backwards" (with a -1 step), deleting rows going up to row number 1.  So your loop might start like this: `For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1`.  And inside the loop you would simply delete a row if `rng.Cells(i) = ""`.  No `else` block needed.  And you wouldn't need `counter`.  I can post a code example if this doesn't make sense.  I think this code might take a long time to execute, and you'd definitely want to turn off screen updating.

Comment: Never mind . it was somethign stupid i did. thank you so much!

Comment: just a question. how do u turn off screen updating? what i usually do is just application.visible= false or something then turn it on later

Answer (score 3):

Here's some simpler code for you:

```
Dim r1 As Range

'Using Tim's range.    
Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("G2"),Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5)) 

'Delete blank cell rows.
r1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Set r1 = Nothing
```

Comment: Hey thanks i changed my code to this instead actually it jsut runs so much faster cuz a loop takes a lot longer. thanks

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out for you. The code still does the loops, it just does it internal to Excel so it's much faster code than VBA.

Comment: I'd give the accept answer to Jon for this one (you can change it I believe). :) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim rng As Range 
Dim counter As Long  

Set rng = Range(Range("G2"),Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5))  
For counter = rng.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1   
   If Len(rng.Cells(counter).Value) = 0 Then rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, it wouldve probably worker but i used Jons code because it didnt require a loop and worked a lot faster. thank you anyways!